# How can I reproduce a Linting Plugin Behavior

Tags: filetype, terminal-buffer

I'm trying to get in to plugin writing, and currently I'm doing some builds (like Latex and LanguageTools checker), and I have in place hotkeys that call for the compilation, and It throws the output message (text streams) in a split term buffer.

What I want to do is to have special rules for the navigation of the output, similar to when linters, reference a line, and by entering that line you jump in to the file/line in question.

To do that should I introduce a new filetype? or is this something? or how should I approach this?

Comment: You might want to have a look at `:help quickfix-window`.

Comment: (I am tempted to close this question as too broad for now). Ralf is right [`:h quickfix`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#quickfix) should be a nice place to start. You should also read [`:h 'makeprg'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27makeprg%27) and [`:h write-compiler-plugin`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#write-compiler-plugin). You should also read the code of the plugin you are trying to mimic that is probably the best way to learn how they do it.

Comment: ok, yes no problem, I didn't knew about `quickfix`, and that was useful. Thanks